# 111-222-1933email@adress.tst hacker

Tags: security, web

I am learning website languages, and i am still a beginner. I am building a website that uses registrations, logins, adds, and so on... First I used PDO in my php in order to prevent mysql injections. Anyway I was hacked, they did not delete the database but it is full of this e-mail 111-222-1933email@adress.tst, and a strange code. I think that they used acunetix to see the leaks of mine website.

My question is: Do you know whats he hacker did, and what measures (besides PDO) can i use in my website to have a little bit more of security?

Comment: Hey, thinking too much ? He may be randomly typing an incorrect email only .

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your point. Can explain again please?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php to create paramerterised queries - only use `quote` as a last resort.

As for your website, it could be anything - review all server and firewall logs as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am already using prepare queries. Sorry i am still really noob and i did not understand what you said.Why are the firewalls of the server involved? The hacker just atacked my website no?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in php, but I think PDO by itself does not protect you from sequel injections when you take input from the user. you still have to use the PDO method quote to protect yourself.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: Ok sorry.I didn't explain me right. I am using prepare queries.